# MongoDB.How to Access to subdocument and get specific part? with spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'd like to get only  List of "grandSubCategory". I tried to use Query in repository such as

```
    @Query("{'subCategory.grandSubCategory.grandSubCategoryName':{$regex: '^?0'}}")
    Category findByName(String name);
```

but it doesn't work. it shows whole collection. and I tried to use MongoTemplete Query but it shows blank.
Here is my collection.

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Electronics",
    "ancestors": [
        "1"
    ],
    "parent": "null",
    "subCategory": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "TV",
            "parent": "1",
            "grandSubCategory": [
                {
                    "id": "7",
                    "name": "LED TV",
                    "parent": "2",
                    "spec": [
                        {
                            "size": "30X30",
                            "material": "plastic",
                            "unit": "CM^x2"
                        }
                    ]}]}]}
```

I only need this part.

```
"grandSubCategory": [
                {
                    "id": "7",
                    "name": "LED TV",
                    "parent": "2",
                    "spec": [
                        {
                            "size": "30X30",
                            "material": "plastic",
                            "unit": "CM^x2"
                        }
                    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create mongo entity using @Document annotation

```
@Document(collection = "category")
```

2.Implement this entity following by your mongo document structure

```
private String id;
private String name;
private List<Ancestor> ancestorList;
private String parent;
private List<SubCategory> subCategoryList;
```

3.Implement repository interface and extends MongoRepository with your findByName() method.

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends MongoRepository<Category, String>
```

4.and try this

```
Category category = categoryRepository.findByName(name);
GrandSubCategory grandSubCategory = category.getSubCategoryList().get(index).getGrandSubCategory();
```

Comment: what supposed to put in get(index) here?

Comment: @CODINNN Your index of subCategory which contains your grandSubCategory list.

Comment: @CODINNN Glad to help!